# Is the departure process of an infinite server queue independent of the arrival process?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Assume we have a $M/M/\infty$ queue with arrival rate $\lambda$ and a service rate $\mu$. From Burke's theorem, the departure process of the queue is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$.

However, what is the relationship between the arrival and departure processes? Are they independent? If not, is it possible to characterize their relationship?

Answer (score 3):

The arrival and departure processes are obviously not independent: suppose that, with some very bad luck, no customers arrived to the system up to now; then (after the completion of the service of those that were there initially) nobody will departure as well.

For a single-server queue, one can, for instance, calculate the covariance of arrival/departure counts: see [The input and output processes in a single-server queue](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416781/the-input-and-output-processes-in-a-single-server-queue); for the $M/M/\infty$ that might be even easier, but I didn't check.